# Linq query with multiple objects in parent child relationship

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have a schema like this

Package -> Lists -> Users

All 'one to many' down the line...

So I want to run a query where I get all packages that a userID matches in users.

```
var pck = (from pk in context.Package
             where pk.Lists[here's my problem]
```

I would assume the navigation properties here would be: `pk.Lists. *Users.UserId* == MyUserId`, however I'm not seeing the navigation properties at the Lists level.

I haven't gotten to more complex EF queries like this yet. I've looked around the web but haven't found anything to make it click. I turn to you stack. Somebody help me see the light!

EDIT: Thanks again stack, I will do my best to pay it forward!
Also, all of these answers enlightened me to the power of ef4!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that a package contains multiple lists, and a list contains multiple users? You could try:

```
var pck = content.Package
     // Outdented just for Stack Overflow's width
     .Where(pk => pk.Lists.Any(list => list.Any(u => u.UserId == myUserId)));
```

Or use a cross-join:

```
var pck = from pk in content.Package
          from list in pk.Lists
          from user in list.Users
          where user.UserId == myUserId
          select ...; // Select whatever you're interested in
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
pk.Lists.Any(l => l.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == MyUserId))
```

Comment: That does make perfect sense, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
context.Packages.Where(p => p.Lists.Any(l => l.Users.Contains(MyUserId)))
```

or, if your user is something other then just a user id,

```
context.Packages.Where(p => p.Lists.Any(l => l.Users.Any(u => u.Id == MyUserId)))
```

Comment: I'm starting to see the light!

Answer (score 1):

```
var packages =
    context.Package.Where(p =>
        p.Lists.Any(l => 
            l.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == MyUserId
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

If the links are non-nullable and direction is package has many lists and list has many users, then the query is pretty easy.

```
var pck = from user in context.Users
          where user.UserId == userId
          select user.List.Package;
```

Comment: this select technique helped me weeks after I asked the question! This page has been a great reference for me! Really opening my eyes to the ease of EF!